# How can I run background timer in React Native?

Tags: javascript, android, ios, react-native, react-native-cli

Is there a way in react-native to run background tasks, that will execute even if the user clears cache or reboot his device(such as android native stopwatch)?

I've tried to implement timer with this library https://github.com/Rapsssito/react-native-background-actions, but it works only when app is foreground or background, if I clear cache or reboot my device the backround service is stopped.

Note: We can't calculate remaining time based on date, cause our timer supports offline usage(so we haven't server time), and if we refer on phone time, user can easily change date and broke timer.

Comment: If your are using Expo you could check this https://docs.expo.dev/versions/latest/sdk/background-fetch/ BackgroundFetch with TaskManager allows you run task in background

Comment: No, we are using react-native-cli